# New to C# WPF .. need to list files , and subfolder files and display in textbox

Tags: c#, wpf

Using C# WPF..

I want to click a button, and display the full contents of folder c:\temp in a textbox. Ideally when you click the button the textbox will populate like this, and refresh on every button click.

\file1.txt

\file2.txt

\new folder1\file3.txt

\new folder2\file4.txt

something like that.. 
I have tried a few different methods using Directory.GetFiles , but cant seem to get the syntax right and not sure how to get it into a textbox.

Could someone give me some example code?
thanks!

Comment: This isn't a site where people write code for you. Show your code, explain what problem you are having, and people *will* help you.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit :**

If you want to get all files in all SubFolders, It's a Recursive algorithm:

```
    private StringBuilder Contents = new StringBuilder();

    private void ExploreAPath(string Path)
    {
        Contents.Append("Contnet of DIR "+ Path + " : \r\n");

        string[] Files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(Path);
        for (int i = 0; i < Files.Length; i++)
        {
            Contents.Append("\t" + Files[i]+"\r\n");
        }

        string[] Directories = System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories(Path);
        for (int i = 0; i < Directories.Length; i++)
        {
            ExploreAPath(Directories[i]);
        }
    }
```

you can use above codes in this way:

```
 ExploreAPath("C:\\Temp");
 textBox.Text = Contents.ToString();
```

Comment: thanks but i dont want a treeview.. i want the output in a textbox. i want the equivalent to dir /s/ b to show up in a textbox

Comment: [Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer)

Comment: I have edited the answer @EJoshuaS, there was a miss understanding from me.